# Why does this code double transpose a vector - is this a noop?

Tags: r, matrix, transpose

I have some legacy R code that does:

```
b = t(a)
c = t(b)
```

What does this code do? Looks like a noop to me. `a` is a vector constructed by `c(1:20)`.

Edit: bonus points on how to do this better.

Comment: `c(1:20)`, aka `1:20` is not a `list`, it's a vector..

Comment: Looks like the author was getting ready to do some matrix ops.

Comment: Well were b,c subsequently used in matrix arithmetic, or not?

Comment: @smci only stuffed into a matrix, although I think a data.frame would be better here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the structure using `str`:

```
> str(a); str(b); str(c)
 int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 int [1, 1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 int [1:20, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The final transpose operation sends the vector `a` to a matrix with 20 rows and 1 column. Equivalent to:

```
c <- as.matrix(c(1:20))
```

Comment: Also equivalent to `matrix(1:20, nrow = 1)`

Comment: Or `b= rbind(1:20); c=cbind(1:20)`

Comment: Note that vectors are treated as _column_ vectors for matrix arithmetic, so you don't want a `t` in your last expression.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's clearer to explicitly set dimensions instead of double `t()`:

```
dim(a) <- c(length(a), 1)
```

which should avoid making a copy.

I've seen this quite a bit in older code, eg for least squares, one might start with:

```
solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% y
```

and, thinking it will save a transpose, refactor to:

```
xt <- t(x)
solve(xt %*% x) %*% xt %*% y
```

and if x isn't necessarily a matrix yet,

```
xt <- t(a)
x <- t(xt)
```

but `t()`s are somewhat of a code smell; 
in this case you are really better off using the other matrix operations eg `solve(crossprod(x), crossprod(x,y))` instead, which gives the same result with less overhead.